# Add additional timeseries based on column values in R

Tags: r

I wonder how to incrementally add timestep by 30mins (Column1) based on successive values under Column2. Appreciate recommendations.
The dput structure is given below:

```
output <- structure(list(Column1 = structure(c(1624874400, 1625241600, 
                                     1625263200, 1625313600, 1625358600, 1625392800, 1627466400, 1627678800, 
                                     1627786800, 1627999200, 1628033400, 1628208000, 1628877600, 1629158400, 
                                     1629986400, 1630749600, 1654821000, 1654869600, 1654884000, 1654956000, 
                                     1654977600, 1655380800, 1655391600, 1655434800, 1655467200, 1655773200, 
                                     1655791200, 1656032400, 1656043200, 1656090000, 1656108000, 1656244800, 
                                     1656334800, 1656374400, 1656459000, 1656486000, 1656572400, 1656684000, 
                                     1657076400, 1657720800, 1657731600, 1657803600, 1657886400, 1658214000, 
                                     1658224800, 1658588400, 1658718000, 1658743200, 1658764800, 1659139200, 
                                     1659160800, 1659247200, 1659258000, 1659369600, 1659528000, 1659553200, 
                                     1659600000, 1660489200, 1660935600, 1660982400, 1660993200, 1661148000, 
                                     1661158800, 1661176800, 1661234400, 1661310000, 1661547600, 1661774400, 
                                     1661785200, 1662195600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
               Column2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
                           7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
                           13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
                           19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
                           25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 
                           31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L)), row.names = c(36L, 
                                                                                        1L, 37L, 2L, 38L, 3L, 39L, 4L, 40L, 5L, 41L, 6L, 42L, 7L, 43L, 
                                                                                        8L, 44L, 9L, 45L, 10L, 46L, 11L, 47L, 12L, 48L, 13L, 49L, 14L, 
                                                                                        50L, 15L, 51L, 16L, 52L, 17L, 53L, 18L, 54L, 19L, 55L, 20L, 56L, 
                                                                                        21L, 57L, 22L, 58L, 23L, 59L, 24L, 60L, 25L, 61L, 26L, 62L, 27L, 
                                                                                        63L, 28L, 64L, 29L, 65L, 30L, 66L, 31L, 67L, 32L, 68L, 33L, 69L, 
                                                                                        34L, 70L, 35L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your desired result? `library(zoo); ats = zoo(, seq(from = min(output$Column1), to =  max(output$Column1), by = "30 min")); new = merge(read.zoo(output), ats)` and then some subsetting or `zoo::na.locf()`-action?